# Error caused by a non-ASCII character in the presence of inputenc + listings

Tags: errors, listings, unicode, input-encodings

Processing the following .tex file with `LaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=example]
ë
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

generates the following 'Package inputenc' error:

[image]

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be in the lstlisting environment. Without it, it compiles just fine. Maybe you can narrow your search from there on.

Comment: I'm giving more information that may be relevant to a person more knowledgeable than me. The error message says its a problem with `inputenc` but it appears to clash with your `lstlisting` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must substitute such chars in listings:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={ë}{{\"e}}1}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=example]
ë
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to [the listings package's manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section 2.5 'Special characters', the paragraph titled 'National characters' on p. 15), it should be possible to type in directly characters with codes 128-255 ('ë' has code 235) by specifying `extendedchars=true`. However specifying this key pair (inside the `lstset` element) doesn't clear the error. Is this a bug in the listings package or do I not understand the manual properly?

Comment: Also: what purpose does the '1' serve in the 'literate' value string?

Comment: You are using utf8 encoding. There ë is not 235 but encoded as `\xC3\xAB`. extendedchars=true doesn't work here. The `1` tells listings how many chars the replacement has, it needs this to calculate the alignment correction.